# how to have locale/tld based urls/routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Is there a way to have different URLs for each locale/tld (especially for SEO reasons) ?

So say if I come thru mysite.us I could have:

http://mysite.com/some-nice-url

and if come thru mysite.org, I could have:

http://mysite.fr/another-very-nice-url

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282346/i18n-locale-in-the-url

Comment: no it's not, please read the question. I don't want a /:locale/ scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ..
  before_filter :domain_locale
  protected
    def domain_locale
      I18n.locale = request.host.split('.').last
    end

  ...
end
```

of course, you could add some more sophistication within `domain_locale`.

So for your routes.rb, you can add constraints like this:

```
match 'soem_nice-url', :to => 'nice#some', :constraints => {:host => 'mysite.com'}
match 'soem_nice-url', :to => 'nice#another', :constraints => {:host => 'mysite.fr'}
```

Comment: extracting the locale isn't an issue, the route per locale is... I want different routes for different locales

Comment: Ah I didn't realize, updated the answer with some help there.